# Confuse about n-dimensions for numpy array?

Tags: numpy

I have a 5-d numpy array, the shape is (5, 1000, 32, 32, 3), which means there are 3 channels of 32*32 pixels, and 1000 samples, 5 different timestamps. How do I print specific 32*32 data, for example, I want to print the 32*32 data from 16th sample, 2nd timestamp, 1st channel?

Comment: index is 0 based.  so [1, 15, :, :, 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a mix of inedexing and slicing this can be done like this:

```
arr = np.random.randint(1000, size=(5, 1000, 32, 32, 3))
result = arr[1, 15, :, :, 0]
print(result.shape)
```

This will output the shape of the result:

> (32, 32)